# How to get an uniform look for Qt and GTK applications in xenial

Tags: themes, kde, qt

Since I upgraded to xenial all the applications but the ones using Qt4 look uniform. For some reason the Qt4 applications like [SpeedCrunch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/speedcrunch) or [Okular](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/okular) use the Plastique theme by default. The [Plastique theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAtTy.jpg) looks completely different from the [Breeze theme](http://fixmynix.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/kwin_lxqt_wm2.jpg) used by default by Qt5, GTK2 and GTK3.

I found the package [qt4-qtconfig](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/qt4-qtconfig) which allows me to chose the Qt4 theme I want to use. qt4-qtconfig seems to work; I changed the Qt4 theme to GTK+.

I would like to use Breeze as Qt4 theme; [kde-style-breeze-qt4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kde-style-breeze-qt4) is installed but it doesn't show in the list. Any idea why?

Comment: I just checked the contents of `kde-style-qtcurve-qt4` (listed by `qt4-qtconfig`) and `kde-style-breeze-qt4` (non listed by `qt4-qtconfig`) and they both place files under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/styles/` so nothing suspect there.

Comment: I still did not find a solution but another workaround: [tool tips are readable again now](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355540#c4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting `Trolltech.conf` from `~/.config`. This file contains the settings for qt4, including a list of available kde-styles. After upgrading the system it often breaks down for some reason.

Comment: This file contains the settings for qt4, including a list of available kde-styles. After upgrading the system it often breaks down. I do not know why.

Comment: Add that to your answer please.